# Utilização de framework em projeto java web

Tags: java, web-service, java-ee, rest, soap

Tenho um projeto em java que executa serviços (SOAP/REST) e temos um framework que dá suporte para isso, gera report, faz chamadas REST e etc, e também tenho um projeto java web (JavaEE) que captura uma lista na View que o usuário digitou. Queríamos que o projeto java web validasse o que vem da View e após manipular, executasse os métodos do projeto soap/framework. Isso é possível ?

Pois conseguimos importar e chamar os métodos deste projeto SOAP e os utilitários do framework, porém quando vamos executar na prática os erros se resumem a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException". Como se não fosse possível ler essas classes.

Comment: Esse erro ocorre quando uma classe não é encontrada. Está adicionando a lib da qual esta classe não localizada pertence no classpath do projeto?

Comment: Estou colocando o projeto java como depedência do Java Web, as libs já não vem como parte de um todo ?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, ainda mais se tratando de outras libs adicionada ao outro projeto.